# Ajax из jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

можно ли вытащить только ajax из jquery ?

если да, то дайте код пжл.

Comment: Эт как так?

Comment: метод ajax вытянуть. jquery с самим ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оставить только `ajax` не получится, потому что эта функциональность довольно сильно завязана на базовом API. Поэтому, можно только исключить "лишние" модули из состава jQuery, воспользовавшись например [jQuery Builder](http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/) (сборка доступна для версий **1.8** и выше).

Также, подробная инструкция о ручной сборке jQuery находится прямо на гитхабе: [How to build your own jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#how-to-build-your-own-jquery).